# Are there any scripts to monitor k8s‘ status？

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

If used on the production system, k8s related services might be down at sometime. Are there any scripts provided that can monitor and restart the services, or i need to develop my scripts and add them to crontab.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean things like the scheduler, apiserver etc. If so, they're already monitored by the kubelet running on that node. Kubelet itself is monitored by a babysitter (your init system- eg upstart, systemd etc). Depending on how your provisioned your cluster, the manifest files for those kube-daemons might be under /etc/kubernetes/manifest, those will have health checks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..How about dashboard (web ui) and kube-dns .. recently we deployed a new cluster and kube-dns was not working, didn't realize until user reported. Looking for a automated test/utility which can validated all the kubernetes required services running properly after new cluster deployment.  Looked into prometheus which helps for continuous monitoring but may not help on new cluster setup validation.